# how to know when page breaks in DOMPDF

Tags: codeigniter, backbone.js, dompdf

I am using DOMPDF library to generate invoices dynamically. My use-case scenario is to leave around 3 inches of space on top of each page. On the first page i created it using a blank div with appropriate height.

Now on second page, it doesn't take the required height from very beginning for obvious reasons. any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of spacer divs just set the page margins in css with:

```
@page { margin-top: 3in; }
```